# Get Access Token for client profile Azure in Python

Tags: python, azure, access-token

I'm looking for a way to get access token from a client profile when working with Azure using Python.

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
```

From the code I get the client profile context but how can I get access token from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find the method to get the access token from a client profile, to get the access token, you could use the [adal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.AuthenticationContext?view=azure-python#methods), use which method depends on your requirement.

For example, I get the access token of a service principal with the client credentials to access the [`Azure Management REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), the given resource is `https://management.azure.com/`.

```
import adal

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'xxxxxxx'

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = 'xxxxxxx'

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'xxxxxxx'


subscription_id = 'xxxxxxx'

authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+TENANT_ID
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource='https://management.azure.com/',
    client_id=CLIENT,
    client_secret=KEY
)

print(token["accessToken"])
```

[image]

Comment: In my example I used `az login` to get client_profile so I wonder if the client profile can return its access token rather than authenticating using service principal info like your example.

Comment: @EagleDev I suppose not, every access token just for one specific resource url, when login with cli, we don’t specify any resource url, also there seems no other method in the official doc to get the token.

Comment: @EagleDev Another workaround for you is to run the cli get access token command directly in python https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token

Comment: Thank you very much Joy Wang. This CLI command works like a charm. I didn't know about it.

Comment: With Python, using an already logged in user's credentials see `SharedTokenCacheCredential` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.sharedtokencachecredential?view=azure-python).